# Best way for obtaining a JTS Geometry from a Spatial4j Geocircle object

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, jts

I have an application which stores a geometry given by a JTS Geometry object (Polygon), but JTS does not use a geodesic context, and I need to store a circle drawn in a geodesic space.

Then I am creating a geodesic circle (created with the spatial4j library) and need to convert it to a jts geometry.

```
SpatialContext.GEO.shapeFactory.circle(lng1, lat1, DistanceUtils.dist2Degrees(circleRadius / 1000, DistanceUtils.EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_KM))
```

So I need to get a polygon representation of that geodesic circle (most accurate possible). How can I do this?. There is another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using JtsSpatialContext (jts 1.15.0) :

```
Circle circle = SpatialContext.GEO.getShapeFactory()
    .circle(lon, lat, DistanceUtils.dist2Degrees(circleRadius / 1000, DistanceUtils.EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_KM));
Geometry circleGeometry = JtsSpatialContext.GEO.getShapeFactory()
    .getGeometryFrom(circle);
```